# Is a good practice Inject IKernel insted business interface dependencies

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

I'm developing and application and I use NInject framework to solve dependencies problems
but the constructors is too big. Some constructors have 5, 8, 10 parameters. and for solve this I have an Idea..

Instead code class like this.

```
public class UserBLL
{
    private IA a;
    private IB b;
    ...
     UserBLL(IA a, IB b, IC c ...)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b
        ...
    }   

}
```

I think code my classes like this.

```
    public class UserBLL
    {
        private IA a;
        private IB b;
        ...
         UserBLL(IKernel kernel)
        {
            this.a = kernel.Get<IA>();
            this.b = kernel.Get<IB>()
            ...
        }   

    }
```

I would like to know if it's a good idea and if it have any issue that I'll face in the future.

Comment: Injecting `IKernel` as a rule is a textbook example of doing it wrong. The point of messing with a DI framework in the first place is to get dependency wireup **out** of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is a good practice Inject IKernel insted business interface dependencies

No, I believe it is not good practice, you are trying to use `IKernel` as *supper factory*, but remember you also create dependency to `IKernel` everywhere in your code, which is not *business class*, it is *infrastructure class*.

In your case, you might violate Single responsibility principle, try to divide your class to smaller classes will be the best suit in this case.

Answer (score 1):

In your second example, you haven't *simplified* the constructor at all. You've added an *extra* dependency. This isn't a good idea. You want your component depending on the interfaces it depends on, not on `IKernel`.

If your class has 8-10 dependencies, that might be a [sign that the class is trying to do too much](http://www.oodesign.com/single-responsibility-principle.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the germ of a good idea here but I would not implement quite like this.  The goal of your kernel object is make the situation clearer not obtuse.  For example I would make it like this:

```
interface IKernel 
{
    public IA GetIA();
    public IB GetIB();      
}
```

Note 1: I would go even farther and actually explain what they stuff is in the interface:

```
interface IKernel
{ 
   public IA GetUserUIPreferences();
   public IB GetPrintingParameters();
}
```

Note 2: It is my expectation that any implementation of IKernel would include functionality which is injected -- otherwise what is the point of having DI

Comment: I suspect that IKernel here is the specific Ninject interface, rather than one the OP has rolled himself.

Comment: @IainGalloway - I believe that was my point, create a holder class to pass as a parameter as op. to the injected class.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not OK to inject the `IKernel` instance.

Injecting a component that is able to arbitrarily resolve other components is called *Service Locator* and is considered an anti-pattern.

The worst thing about a Service Locator is that it's no longer clear what a certain class depends on. This creates a maintenance problem that may not be obvious right away, but will bite you later.

Here's a good article on why it's not a good idea to use a Service Locator: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx

Regarding the issue of having too many parameters in the constructor: consider altering the design. In most cases, this is a problem of applying the Single Responsibility Principle, as Iain Galloway suggested in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14691407/390819). 
Basically, you can try to break apart independent pieces of logic in separate classes that will become dependencies of the current class, but will, at the same time, "steal" some of the existing dependencies.

So, for example, if class `A` has 10 dependencies, you may split the logic into three classes: `B`, `C` and `D`. Each of these will probably have 3-4 of the dependencies that were previously used by `A` directly.

If you think that 3-4 dependencies is also too much, you can repeat this process at those for those smaller classes as well.